# Prevent closing of other people's RDP sessions on Windows Server

Tags: remote-desktop, group-policy, windows, windows-server-2016

I work on a windows server machine where all users have admin privileges and can, using the task manager, terminate each other's sessions  (`taskmanager -> users -> select user -> sign off -> confirm`).

Sometimes people close sessions and close the wrong one (likely by accident) and this can lead to data loss. What would be some (technological) measures (group policy, regedit?) to protect sessions from being closed remotely (i.e. from another open session on the same server) and minimize chance of this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it. You say yourself they all work with the same user account, so the sessions are not "from different people" as far as the computer is concerned.

You can also not solve antisocial behavior with technology - you take the people aside and explain them why their services are no longer required. Period. If people do destructive operations "for trolling" (as you say) then this is a reason for termination.